# MySQL Query Checking Availability of a specific room depends on two input date

Tags: mysql

I am stuck on how can I check the *available rooms* depends on the *two input date* from the user.

Let's say there is a user that trying to *check_in* with the date `2018-05-05` up to `2018-05-06`.

Upon submitting the form by the user, the system should check if what room is available to that specific date.

The results return should be only two types of room:

```
Room_Name |  Price
standard  |  300
premier   |  900
```

**MySQL Tables**

```
Reservations
ID | User | Check_in   | Check_out
1  | john | 2018-05-03 | 2018-05-07
2  | jane | 2018-05-04 | 2018-05-07

Reservations_Details
ID | Reservation_ID | Rooms_ID
 5 |      1         |   2
 6 |      2         |   3

Rooms
ID | Rooms_Type_ID | Room_No | Room_Status_ID
 1 |     1        |  101     |      1
 2 |     1        |  102     |      2
 3 |     1        |  103     |      1
 4 |     2        |  201     |      3
 5 |     3        |  301     |      1
 6 |     3        |  302     |      1

Rooms_Type
ID | Room_Name | Price | Units
 1 | standard  |  300  |  3
 2 | deluxe    |  600  |  1
 3 | premier   |  900  |  2

Room_Status
ID | Status 
 1 | vacant
 2 | occupied
 3 | reserved
```

**Query**

I have a query like this but this is only for the available rooms with *status = vacant*

```
SELECT rooms_type.room_name, rooms_type.price 
    FROM rooms_type
    JOIN rooms ON rooms.rooms_type_id = rooms_type.id 
    WHERE rooms.status_id = 1 
    GROUP BY rooms_type.room_name
```

I can't think of how can I produce the results in one query if it is possible.

Comment: If you have room status , you can directly find available room

Comment: Yes, I know but how can I tie it up in the date fields? that's my main issue

Comment: which language you are using

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have start_date and end_date. It will give you id of all available rooms

Try this query

```
SELECT Rooms.Room_No
FROM Rooms
JOIN Reservations_Details ON rooms.ID = Reservations_Details.Rooms_ID 
JOIN Reservations ON Reservations.ID = Reservations_Details.Reservation_ID 
WHERE (start_date < Check_in AND start_date < Check_out AND 
       end_date < Check_in AND end_date < Check_out) OR
      (start_date > Check_in AND start_date > Check_out AND 
       end_date > Check_in AND end_date > Check_out)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Room_No FROM Reservations WHERE (pickupDate <= '$pickupDate' AND returnDate >= '$pickupDate') 
            OR (pickupDate <= '$returnDate' AND returnDate >= '$returnDate')
            OR (pickupDate >= '$pickupDate' AND returnDate <= '$returnDate')
```